# Clearbox JS "messages"

Tags: javascript, image, viewer

I am currently running Clearbox JS on my site so that users may view a larger version of an image once they have visited the images page. Now, I just recently implemented this and I have noticed that on every single page at the top of the page Clearbox JS echos the command that it is doing. Whether it be initializing, or viewing an image, or event rotating an image. I really do not want this message popping up at all. I would much rather being required to put a link somewhere on the website to the developers website then having to deal with this. If anybody knows how to remove this, please answer. I am providing a link to the website so that you know what I am doing as well as a pastebin link to the clearbox.js file which is the config file.

website: www.dsdwebdesign.net/bootstrap_apgnew/index.php 
pastebin: http://pastebin.com/NgBgc34X

Comment: It would help if you linked to the plugin's homepage. I did a quick search and nothing stood out to me as the official Clearbox site

Comment: You also get a downvote for not pasting a concise, standalone example in your question. I nor anybody else wants to wade through your pastebin trying to understand what it is or does

Comment: You down voted me because you couldn't tell what Clearbox JS was. Anybody who goes to google and types it in can clearly tell that the first to link point to their website and their facebook page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this somewhere in your page, or the cb_style.css file (but make sure you read their conditions, I am not sure if you are allowed to do this with this piece of software):

```
#CB_OSD{
   display:none!important;
}
```

It should hide the box at the top.